# Build a room dynamically

Tags: three.js

I need to build a room with three.js, basically, walls, floor, and doors.
But it needs to be dynamic, so I can change the properties, sizes, etc., in the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no "make.my.game" yet,but you can start from this example:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter

I would add a DAT.GUI to change models as in:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_md2

And that's all for now; the rest depends on your implementation logic (paper helps in these situations).